# Does the order of static and volatile keywords matter?

Tags: c

```
volatile static int i;
```

and

```
static volatile int i;
```

what is the difference between the two? How does the compiler see this?

Answer (score 8):

The order is irrelevant. `static` is a storage duration.

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
>
> 3 An object whose identifier is
> declared with external or internal
> linkage, or with the storage-class
> specifier static has static storage
> duration. Its lifetime is the entire
> execution of the program and its
> stored value is initialized only once,
> prior to program startup.

and:

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
>
> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
> implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring
> to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine,
> as described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the
> object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the
> unknown factors mentioned previously.114) What constitutes an access to an object that
> has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, you can specify them in either order.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the order doesn't matter but the following is also valid

```
static int volatile i;
```

which shows that the order in general is relevant, since you can't put `static` after `int`. `static` qualifies the variable, `volatile` and `const` qualify the type.

Answer (score 1):

Both mean the same

Wikepedia gives you information on them
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable